# How to debug a function(that can only work on a real device) with different SDK version?

Tags: ios

I am facing a compatibility issue .

After iOS SDK 10.2+ , when you use function `openURL` to call someone , it will show a alertView first , but between 10.0~10.1 , it won't show this alertView. I want to find the **Version differences** of this function but the Simulator can not respond to this function , it means that this function only work on really device , but i don't have a iPhone with v8.0 or v9.0 SDK , how can i test the function's **Version differences**?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe in simulator, for using openUrl, you may have to save the web page on simulator directory and use url for this page.

Comment: opneURL ，if the url is a web page , it works , but if the url is ''tel:xxx' , it cannot work .

Comment: @Kira Because of you are running it on simulator?! Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1628895/1122517

Comment: yes , on the simulator , because i want to test the Version differences , only the simulator has different version sdk , my iphone's sdk is only 10.2 and cannot change.